# Not allowed to load local resource: blob:blobinternal:///

Tags: ios, cordova, webrtc, cordova-plugins

I am using https://github.com/BasqueVoIPMafia/cordova-plugin-iosrtc and I am having a hard time to allow ios 11 to work with internal blobs.

Do you have any idea how to configure cordova 7 (ios engine 4.5+) in order to make this works?

Thank you!

Comment: also having this issue

Answer (score 1):

what actually fixed it for me was changing `video.srcObject = stream;` to `video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);`

Comment: yes, another inconsistency between chrome and ios. if your code needs to work on chrome and on ios webviews, you need code to check which browser you're on before running the correct command